# How do I prevent the language code being stripped from the URL pathway?

Tags: uri

**Problem**

> When trying to link to **example.org/fr/node/1**, links directs to
> **example.org/node/1**.
>
> Same problem when using direct pathways instead of node links. Trying
> to link to **example.org/fr/a-propos/notre-equipe** will direct to
> **example.org/a-propos/notre-equipe** and break.

**Tried**

> the WYSIWIG and layout builders have multiple options for embedding
> links. All of them work in saving the correct link when the page is
> updated:
>
> [image]
>
> But hovering over the link shows that the language code has been
> ignored:
> [image]

I'm viewing the page "/fr/a-propos/notre-equipe" in French and trying to edit a custom rich text block. The block basically fails to update when editing the link destination in the HTML source from /node/1 to /es/node/1:

[image]

If I click the link in this site, it redirects either to one of two places:

1. if the link is /fr/node/1 it redirects to the English page at /node/1.
2. if the link is /fr/a-propos/notre-equipe it redirects to a 404 page (because the link fails to update and the browser is looking for /a-propos/notre-equipe instead of /fr/a-propos/notre-equipe

Using the tmgmt module. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which language are you viewing the page in? What happens if you click the link in said language?

Comment: French. The link breaks because it's not updating correctly. I've updated the question with more detail.